# Сортировка массива C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Написал сортировку, но выводит неправильно: пишет `(4, 100000000000, 3, 3)`.

```
array<int> ^name = { 3, 4, 3, 1000000000 };
int b;

for (int i = 0; i < name->Length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < name->Length - 1; j++) {    
        if (name[j] < name[j + 1]) {
            b = name[j];
            name[j] = name[j + 1];
            name[j + 1] = b;    
        }    
    }

    Console::WriteLine(name[i]);    
}
```

Comment: Называется "пузырьковая сортировка". Алгоритм не очень надежный, редко бывает эффективнее алгоритма быстрой сортировки, разве что, если требуется отсортировать небольшую последовательность, скажем, не более 30 элементов.

Comment: Нафига внешний цикл крутить name->Length раз? Обычно у пузырьковой остановка производится по отсутствию перемещения элементов во внутреннем цикле. (То, что сортировка по убыванию, уже отметил @Baho)

Answer (score 3):

1)

```
if (name[j] < name[j + 1]) {
```

- это сортировка по убыванию, по возрастанию наоборот

2)  Выводит неправильно потому, что вывод в неправильном месте

нужно примерно так сделать в конце (после сортировки):

```
for (int i = 0; i < name->Length; i++) {
    Console::WriteLine(name[i]);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сортировка линейных массивов легко осуществляется встроенной функцией .NET [Array::Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.array.sort.aspx).

```
using namespace System;

int main() {
    array <int>^ x = { 1, 3, 2, 5, 4 };

    Array::Sort(x);

    for (int i = 0; i < x->Length; i++)
        Console::Write("{0} ", x[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У тебя происходит переполнение при инициализации массива. Убери пару нулей из большого числа, либо замени array<int> на array<long long>. Только не пойму, почему число выводится правильно...

Comment: Проблема не в числе, там всего 1млрд в примере

Comment: А да, я не там нули считал. Вверху у него 100 миллиардов написано.